# How to write unit test with mocks when method uses ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have a SpringMVC project. The method from my FooController that I want to test is:

```
@GetMapping("/view/{fooId}")
public String view(@PathVariable String fooId, Model model) throws FooNotFoundException, JsonProcessingException {
    Foo foo = fooService.getFoo(fooId);
    model.addAttribute("fooId", foo.getId());
    model.addAttribute("foo", new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(foo));
    return "foo/view";
}
```

The test that I've written is:

```
public class FooControllerTest {
    @Mock
    private Foo mockFoo;
    @Mock
    private FooService mockFooService;
    @InjectMocks
    private FooController controller;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testView() throws Exception {
        String fooId = "fooId";
        when(mockFooService.getFoo(fooId)).thenReturn(mockFoo);
        when(mockFoo.getId()).thenReturn(fooId);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/foo/view/" + fooId))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(model().attribute("fooId", fooId))
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("foo"))
                .andExpect(forwardedUrl("foo/view"));
    }

}
```

This test fails with `java.lang.AssertionError: No ModelAndView found`. 
When I debug the test, I see it goes wrong when my `mockFoo` is given to `new ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString()`. So I think mocked objects cannot be serialized. How do I work around this, how do I make my test pass?

---

What have I tried already:

- I commented the line `model.addAttribute("foo", new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(foo));` in FooController, this way the test worked (but not the way I want my method to work)! So now I know this is where it goes wrong.
- I commented the line `.andExpect(model().attributeExists("foo"))` in FooControllerTest, it still produced the above AssertionError.
- Googling and StackOverflowing, but I could find something usable.

Comment: Do not instantiate the `ObjectMapper`, but Inject it to your Controller instead, and then you can easily mock it.

Comment: @Ruben Ah, yes. Then I could use `when(mockObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(mockFoo)).thenReturn(...)`. Thank you. For now, I still go with my colleagues answer, because I understand his point of view that simple POJOs do not need to  be mocked.

Comment: with the benefit that you do not need to instantiate the `ObjectMapper` in each request (it's thread safe as long as you do not change the configuration), what translates in better performance for your app (less CPU, less GC)

Comment: @Ruben You're right again, my colleague also pointed that out. It is however a one time thing (the user goes once to "/floo/view/{id}" and then he stays there for some time).

Comment: Agree with @J.Kamans. Make sure you return proper value and for negative test case throw proper exception. Most of exception deprecated for JsonProcessException. I used one of subclass's *JsonGenerationException(String msg, Throwable rootCause, JsonGenerator g)* which is public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague suggested the following: instead of using `mockFoo`, create a new Foo object and used it like so:

```
@Test
public void testView() throws Exception {
    String fooId = "fooId";
    Foo foo = new Foo(fooId);
    when(mockFooService.getFoo(fooId)).thenReturn(foo);

    mockMvc.perform(get("/foo/view/" + fooId))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(model().attribute("fooId", fooId))
            .andExpect(model().attributeExists("foo"))
            .andExpect(forwardedUrl("foo/view"));
}
```

This works. I always thought you have to mock each and every object you're not testing (so in a Controller, you mock everything except the controller itself). But because `Foo` is a simple POJO, it doesn't need to be mocked.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the Spy annotation when doing the InjectMocks annotation like this

```
@InjectMocks
@Spy
private FooController controller;
```

And yes do not instantiate ObjectMapper or any classes inside the controller. You will be forced to use PowerMockito if you do so. Try injecting them in the controller like @Ruben Mentioned.

Injecting dependencies is always easier for testing.